# Should a virtualenv have it's own "argparse"?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment, that's used by multiple people on multiple machines. I ran into a problem today that a user couldn't import argparse.

The problem ended up being that I am running python2.7.10_2 and he is running 2.7.13. The python in the virtualenv, is mine, so 2.7.10_2. This meant that it was looking for system libraries in the wrong place (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2, instead of 2.7.13/) However, I thought that the point of virtual environments is that all of the libraries are in the venv, and so it doesn't matter what versions of python you actually have installed anywhere.

However, it seems that there is no argparse in venv/lib/site-packages, and so it uses my original PYTHONPATH, which isn't correct for the user.

For other reasons, the virtualenv was originally created with the relocatable flag, so that isn't the problem.

ETA: 
The solution I came up with (hideous kludge though it is) Is that I had the user symlink 2.7.13 to 2.7.10_2, so it can find his original libraries.

Comment: virtualenv has a creation-time configurable flag determining whether you want libraries outside the virtualenv to be accessible -- though *standard-library* modules (which, for Python 2.7, includes argparse) should always be accessible.

Comment: That said, a virtualenv is tied to the Python runtime that created it -- they aren't meant to be shared across machines with different runtimes installed, as you're doing here.

Comment: yeah, no-site-packages is set by default. I assumed that that included standard library. I guess it doesn't Good to know! (Feel free to post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.)

Comment: `--no-site-packages` isn't intended to exclude the standard library, but since virtualenvs aren't intended to be portable across different interpreter versions, we hit a corner case. (I wouldn't call it a "bug", since it's being used outside of the intended environment -- which assumes that the specific interpreter it was created with is available).

Comment: ...might I ask how this is shared? If it's a NFS mount or such, for instance, why not have the Python interpreter that the virtualenv depends on located on that mount?

Comment: t's shared via dropbox. The dropboxes are mounted in different locations on different machines (NOT my choice. Not my power to change...) That's why I needed relocatable in the first place... but that doesn't apply to the base libraries it seems...

Comment: Correct -- "relocatable" means that your virtualenv can be moved into a different location on the filesystem without breaking it. It *does not* guarantee that it can be copied to a different machine, used with a different Python interpreter version, etc; your use case goes well beyond what is supported, and I'd generally advise coming up with a different solution.

Comment: (Example, re: "different solution": A wrapper which generates a local virtualenv in a dotfile under the user's home directory; populates it with libraries named in a requirements.txt; and then uses it to run your actual script would do nicely).